# Breeze js Non-EF hasServerMetadata

Tags: breeze

I'm running the following using Breeze.js with Asp.Net WebAPI. I can query my service using OData protocol and I can see JSON data in the response, but the .then() and .fail() callbacks aren't firing so the view model never gets the data.  Is that because I'm missing the metadata?

```
/// <reference path="..\breeze.debug.js" />

(function (root) {
    var dataService = new breeze.DataService({
        serviceName: 'api/breezesample',
        hasServerMetadata: false
    });

    var altMs = new breeze.MetadataStore({
        namingConvention: breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase
    });

    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
        dataService: dataService,
        metadataStore: altMs
    });

    // define the viewmodel
    var vm = {
        todos: ko.observableArray(),
        includeDone: ko.observable(false),
        show: ko.observable(false)
    };

    // start fetching Todos
    getTodos();

    // re-query when "includeDone" checkbox changes
    //vm.includeDone.subscribe(getTodos);

    // bind view to the viewmodel
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

    /* Private functions */

    // get Todos asynchronously
    // returning a promise to wait for     
    function getTodos() {

        var query = breeze.entityModel.EntityQuery.from("todos");

        if (!vm.includeDone()) {
            query = query.where("IsDone", "==", false);
        }

        return manager
            .executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);
    };

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        vm.todos.removeAll();

        var todos = data.results;
        todos.forEach(function (todo) {
            vm.todos.push(todo);
        });

        vm.show(true); // show the view
    }

    function queryFailed(error) {
        alert("Query failed: " + error.message);
    }

}(window));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.  You will also need to add your metadata to the 'altMs' via addEntityType method calls.  Make sure you get the latest version of breeze as well, v.0.78.x.  The 'breeze.entityModel' in your code is no longer needed.

```
var DataService   = breeze.DataService;
var MetadataStore = breeze.MetadataStore;
var EntityManager = breeze.EntityManager;

var dataService = new DataService({
    serviceName: altServiceName,
    hasServerMetadata: false
});

var altMs = new MetadataStore({
    namingConvention: NamingConvention.camelCase
});

return new EntityManager({
    dataService: dataService,
    metadataStore: altMs
});
```

Comment: I'm using version 0.78.2 which I pulled from NuGet yesterday.

What if I don't know or have access to the metadata?  Ideally, I'd like to use Breeze to query any web service supporting OData protocol without having to add metadata to my code. Is that possible?  @john-papa made a similar request for an example in this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607714/is-breeze-server-side-metadata-mandatory-or-can-it-be-be-defined-client-side) so I assumed it was possible.

Comment: Yes, you can use the code above. But without metadata the results are not added to the EntityManager and not wrapped as 'observable' objects. An query results for types without metadata are just plain java objects.

Comment: Thanks, Jay. I'm not getting an error now and I can see JSON data being returned from my web service but .then(callback) and .fail(callback) never fire.  Any ideas?  I've included all my source code above.

Comment: Can you post a small example what your getTodos method looks like?

Comment: Jay - I updated the original question with more code. See above.

Comment: I am unable to repro your issue, but ... there is now a non-EF example available in the samples in breeze v 0.82.1. called ToDo-NoEF